# How to include a jar on disk as Gradle compile dependency

Tags: jar, gradle

> compile files('lib/ssi-jar-with-dependencies.jar')

Does not work.  It does not break the script but does not include the dependency either.

Answer (score 0):

The above declaration is correct (assuming you put it in the right place). Either the path is wrong, or there is some other problem with the build script (or the Jar).

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Flat directory repository](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec%3aflat_dir_resolver):

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib1', 'lib2'
    } }
```

Comment: Let's say you put foo.jar in lib.  How would you set foo as a dependency with the flatDir repository.  IE in a subproject where I need foo, "compile 'foo'" ??

Comment: For example put the jar as $project_dir/lib/my-jar-1.0.jar
add
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}
and use it as
**compile ":my-jar:1.0"**